# Query that will result in a list of customer names and the average order value made by each customer

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database and I need to create a query that will retrieve a list of customer names and the average order value made by each customer.
I tried:

```sql
SELECT c.customer_name, AVG(COUNT(o.order_id)*f.price) AS 'avgorderprice' 
FROM Customers c 
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id 
INNER JOIN F_in_Or fio ON o.order_id = fio.order_id 
INNER JOIN Films f ON fio.film_id = f.film_id;
```

This is my database structure:
[image: database structure]
[image]

But I get an error, what can be wrong?

Comment: A schema of the tables would be of help

Comment: Please add more details about the error message you're getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I get an error, what can be wrong ?

You are trying to use an aggregate function **Count** within an aggregate function and getting a MISUSE OF AN AGGREGATE FUNCTION.

i.e. - *`> misuse of aggregate function COUNT()`*

Additionally you are not **GROUP**'ing your results and thus will receive the entire average rather than a per-customer average.

- *Aggregate functions work on a **GROUP** the default being all unless a **`GROUP BY`** clause places the rows into GROUPS.*

You could instead of `AVG(COUNT(o.order_id)*f.price)` use `sum(f.price) / count(*)`. However, there is an average aggregate function **`avg`**. So avg(f.price)' is simpler.

Additionally as you want an average per customer you want to use a `GROUP BY c.customer` clause.

Thus you could use :-

```
SELECT 
    c.customer_name, 
    avg(f.price) AS 'avgorderprice' --<<<<< CHANGED
    FROM Customers c 
    LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id 
    INNER JOIN F_in_Or fio ON o.order_id = fio.order_id 
    INNER JOIN Films f ON fio.film_id = f.film_id 
    GROUP BY c.customer_name --<<<<< ADDED
;
```

This would result in something like :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
SELECT c.customer_name, AVG(f.price) AS 'avgorderprice' FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id LEFT JOIN F_in_Or fio ON o.order_id = fio.order_id LEFT JOIN Films f ON fio.film_id = f.film_id;
```